# How will Back-Bonding affect molecular geometry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, ions, molecular-structure

While going through a textbook, I came across the following line:

> $\ce{R3C-}$ is pyramidal while $\ce{(CN)3C-}$ is planar due to lack of back bonding from the lone pair of carbon atom into the $\pi^*$ orbital of the $\ce{CN}$ group.

I am having trouble understanding how exactly back-bonding occurs in the first species and how it causes the structure to be pyramidal while the latter is planar.

Comment: You might think of it as resonance instead of back-bonding...

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32354/is-the-conjugate-base-of-trinitromethane-aromatic-what-is-y-aromaticity