# Why isn't trinitramide planar?

Tags: molecular-structure

[image]

The lewis structure of trinitramide has four major resonance structures, whereby the lone pairs of the central nitrogen can resonate with the nitro groups.

This seems to indicate that each of the nitrogen atoms would be sp2 hybridized, and the entire molecule would be planar. In fact, the Wikipedia ball-and-stick image for trinitramide seems to indicate it so.

[image]

However, based on quantum mechanical [calculations](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100128a005), trinitramide is in fact non-planar. Why is this so? What drives its non-planarity?

Comment: Steric hindrance, maybe?

Comment: I would assume it’s a combination of steric and charge repulsion between the oxygen atoms. The experimentally determined structure in https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201007047 shows the nitro groups essentially at right angles to each other.

Comment: I have extensively written about the isoelectronic trinitromethanide anion: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/32354/4945

Comment: Doesn't the paper you have linked tell more than what we can presumably say? Interestingly, they not only say isn't planar, but pyramidal. There should be a comment atop the calculations. Otherwise take it at the level of their work. Perhaps one could calculate a different situati

Comment: Are there 4 electron domains around the central nitrogen (3 bonds to NO2 groups and one lone pair)? That would suggest trigonal pyramidal geometry.

Comment: The presence of nitro groups attached to the central nitrogen would lead to resonance between each nitro group and the central notrogen, which would have in fact made us expect trigonal planar geometry infact. The reason then, for the actual non-planarity, is best explained by the reasoning put forward by Andrew's comment above. Essentially, in the 3D confirmer as shown [here](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Trinitramide#section=3D-Conformer) the nitro groups are at right angles at each other to minimise steric as well as charge repulsion between the oxygens

Comment: A similar rationale regarding steric repulsion follows for the propeller-like arrangement of the three phenyl groups in [triphenylphosphine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triphenylphosphine#:~:text=Triphenylphosphine%20crystallizes%20in%20triclinic%20and,of%20the%20three%20phenyl%20groups.)

Comment: Also a similar repulsion between ortho hydrogens is the usual explanation for non planarity of [biphenyl](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Biphenyl#section=2D-Structure) systems